# tflearn 3d tensor - ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 15, 15)

Tags: python, networking, machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn

First time encounter such a problem. Test the neural network of tflearn gives an error. When attempting to test this code Python generates an error. With conv_2d had no such problems.

My code:

    `import numpy as np
    import random
    import tflearn
    from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
    from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_3d, max_pool_3d
    from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression`

```
trainX = [[[random.randint(0,3) for col in range(15)] for row in range(15)] for x in range(50)]
testX = [[[random.randint(0,3) for col in range(15)] for row in range(15)] for x in range(10)]

trainY = [[0,1] for x in range(100)]
testY = [[0,1] for x in range(10)]


idnn = 'test_cnn'

network = input_data(shape=[None, 15, 15,15, 1])
network = conv_3d(network, 10, 3, activation='relu')

network = max_pool_3d(network, 2)
network = conv_3d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_3d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')

network = max_pool_3d(network, 2)
network = fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu')
network = dropout(network, 0.5)
network = fully_connected(network, 2, activation='softmax')
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam',
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                     learning_rate=0.001)



# Train using classifier
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(trainX, trainY, n_epoch=10, shuffle=True, validation_set=(testX, testY),
          show_metric=True, batch_size=5, run_id= idnn)    
pred = model.predict(testX)
```

This gives an error tflearn when attempting to test code.

```
    ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 15, 15) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 15, 15, 15, 1)'
```

What could be the problem ? Please Someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `trainX` and `testX` have shape (50, 15, 15). However, in

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 15, 15,15, 1])
```

You specified the shape of the input to be (None, 15, 15, 15, 1). These shapes do not match. The `None` may represent any number, but the shapes should match.

For example, you could take `trainX` and `testX` to be of shape (50, 15, 15,15,1).

Answer (score 0):

Let's find out, what is the conv_3d network?

There is a information from [tflearn](http://tflearn.org/layers/conv/#convolution-3d) documentation.

> Input

`5-D Tensor [batch, in_depth, in_height, in_width, in_channels]`.

> Output

```
5-D Tensor [filter_depth, filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels].
```

The `trainX` and `testX` data should be the same size. Because you are using the `testX` data in `validation_set`.

Your `trainX` and `testX` data look like 2D data set. `50x(15,15)`, `10x(15,15)`
If you would like to use conv_3d, you have to make the same size your `train` and `test` data. (`50x(15,15)`, `50x(15,15)`).

And also I saw your target data `trainY` is not the same size as your train data `trainX`.